# OutOfMemoryError while resizing Bitmap

Tags: blackberry, resize-image

I am trying to resise a Bitmap image using bitmap.scaleInto function. I got the out of memory exception while trying to do that for an image having a 2MB size. How can I make a resize of large image files without getting such an exception?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code for resizing the image?

Comment: "image having a 2MB size" - unfortunatelly this does not tell us anything about image dimentions (width x height), so it's unclear what source Bitmap size you have. Also you don't tell whether you downscaling or upscaling.

Comment: BlackBerry devices have had some issues dealing with larger bitmaps, but this depends more on resolution, rather than byte size. Arhimed is correct in pointing out that knowing the dimensions of the bitmap, and your use, would be much more useful than knowing the size of the image.

Comment: Resizing of images is done because I need image picker from the memory of the device. So I am searching for images on the device, and then for each one, I am reading it using the inputstream and then creating a bitmap, resizing the bitmaps and adding them to the form. This is taking too much time and sometimes the device is running out of memory. How to solve this!?

Comment: The function to resize the bitmaps are the one presented by RIM... bitmap.scaleInto function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be closed, solution is here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Beginner-OutOfMemory-Error-when-Resizing-Bitmap/m-p/706427/highlight/true#M137817